# mutiple inline script exec order in html?

Tags: javascript

why console order is 2 3 1 ？
each script seem to wait promise task,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      setTimeout(() => console.log(1), 0);
      Promise.resolve(2).then(console.log);
    </script>
    <script>
      console.log(3);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

I thought it would be 3 2 1. but obviously I was wrong

why 2 output before 3, Promise then callback will exec in nexttick,and console.log(3); is sync task.

Comment: the most meaningful thing to say there it's why `setTimeout` doesn't execute the code immediately as someone would expect.  From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) _"If this parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute "immediately", or more accurately, the next event cycle."_ . [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) on SO more details about that. To further expand "next event cycle", it means that the func is queued to be executed as soon as the current script finished execution

Answer (score 0):

the event loop in macrotask include the rendering. you can see the standard of  [Processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model)

so the order is
setTimeout => micro task promise =>  render script  => setTimeout function exec